# Comments pushing sidebar down

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, responsive

I'm working on making my first responsive WordPress theme. I ran into some trouble while working on single.php and comments.php. For some reason the comments section is pushing the sidebar down. I'm also having trouble making the comments responsive, which I think might be part of the issue because when I remove the comments section entirely from single.php, everything lines up correctly.

Here is a link to the page I'm speaking of http://mockup.artxwpn.com/2017/01/19/hello-world/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the css from `.container::after, .row::after, .u-cf` from `display: block;` to `display: inline;` at line `419` from `style.css`

Full example:

```
.container::after, .row::after, .u-cf {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: This helped loads!

Comment: I was wondering if I can get your advice on another page with a similar problem. My sidebar is being pushed down now and I can't seem to figure out what's causing it. [link](http://mockup.artxwpn.com/lifestyle/)

Comment: Looks like you got it, huh?

Comment: Yes indeed :) Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score -1):

It's because your `#comment` and `#submit` has a fixed value of width.
Try using media queries, or just change the `width:600px` to `width:100%`
Like this:

```
#comment {
        background: #fff;
        color: #000;
        border-color: #efefef;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 10px 15px 10px 0px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
        border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    }


  #submit {
        width: 100%;
        height: 55px;
        font-size: 17px;
        line-height: normal;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        color: #fff;
        background: #000;
        font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

Comment: Will do! Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

You have closed the row before the sidebar , you need to keep in one row so that it is aligned properly . 
You html structure should be like this . It will aligned your sidebar correctly

```
<div class="row">
<div class="eight columns" id="content"></div>
<div class="four columns" id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

For you now your html structure is like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="eight columns" id="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="four columns" id="sidebar"></div>
```

Comment: Oh my I feel so foolish, I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Your sidebar is not held within the same `<div class="row"></div>`, it seems you are loading it afterwards.

Try including it within the same `row`.

```
<div class="row"><!-- Open row -->
     <div class="eight columns" id="content"> <!-- Open Content -->
         <!--Post Content-->
     </div> <!-- Close Content -->
     <div class="four columns" id="sidebar"> <!-- Open Sidebar -->
         <!--Sidebar Content-->
     </div> <!-- Close Sidebar -->
</div> <!-- Close row -->
```

I tested this within Google Chrome console and it works.

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I had the row closed before the sidebar and didn't even realise.